# Fabric miss version name at distribution to beta

Tags: android, google-fabric

After updating gradle wrapper to **4.1** and android plugin to **3.0.1** fabric miss version name at distribution titles at beta (titles contain only version suffix)

root build.gradle contains:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
}
```

app build.gradle contains:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the section of your build.gradle where you're setting the version names and also screenshots of what Beta is displaying?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for fabric dependencies

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.4.1'
}
```

Comment: Could not find io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.4.1.
anyway I use higher version of plugin

Comment: use this link https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin  to find out the latest version of fabric gradle plugin for